# Integration of CDF

Tags: integration

How to integrate the cumilative distribution function of standard normal distribution? The CDF is itself an integral, so should it be a double integral of pdf?

Comment: Integration over $\mathbb R$? Then the integral wil take value $+\infty$ because the funcion is positive and increasing. This for every CDF.

Comment: Yes, but what about definite integral?

Comment: Sorry, but what is "definite integral" in this context? Do you mean the anti-derivative of $\Phi(x)$?

Comment: I mean integral over some interval

Comment: [WolframAlpha can integrate it.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+CDF(NormalDistribution(0,1),+m)+for+m%3D0..x)

Answer (score 3):

Using integration by parts,
\begin{eqnarray}
 \int_\limits{a}^b\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)(y)dy &=& \left[y\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)(y)\right]_{y=a}^{y=b}-\int_\limits{a}^by\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)'(y)dy\\
&=& b\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)(b)-a\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)(a)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\limits{a}^b\frac{d}{dy}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy\\
&=&b\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)(b)-a\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)(a) + \frac{e^{-\frac{b^2}{2}}-e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\ .
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: +1.  You could write this result as $$\int_\limits{a}^b\int_\limits{-\infty}^y\phi(x)\, dx\,dy =\int_\limits{a}^b\Phi(y)\,dy = \bigl(b\Phi(b)+\phi(b) \bigr) -  \bigl(a\Phi(a)+\phi(a)\bigr)$$

Answer (score 1):

For a general CDF $F$ we find:

$$\int_{a}^{b}F\left(x\right)dx=\int\mathbf{1}_{(a,b]}\left(x\right)\int\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,x]}\left(y\right)dF\left(y\right)dx=\int\int\mathbf{1}_{(a,b]}\left(x\right)\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,x]}\left(y\right)dxdF\left(y\right)=$$$$\int\int\mathbf{1}_{(a,b]}\left(x\right)\mathbf{1}_{[y,+\infty)}\left(x\right)dxdF\left(y\right)$$

- If $y\leq a$ then $\int\mathbf{1}_{(a,b]}\left(x\right)\mathbf{1}_{[y,+\infty)}\left(x\right)dx=b-a$
- If $a<y\leq b$ then $\int\mathbf{1}_{(a,b]}\left(x\right)\mathbf{1}_{[y,+\infty)}\left(x\right)dx=b-y$
- If $y> b$ then $\int\mathbf{1}_{(a,b]}\left(x\right)\mathbf{1}_{[y,+\infty)}\left(x\right)dx=0$

so that:

$$\int\int\mathbf{1}_{(a,b]}\left(x\right)\mathbf{1}_{[y,+\infty)}\left(x\right)dxdF\left(y\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{a}\left(b-a\right)dF\left(y\right)+\int_{a}^{b}\left(b-y\right)dF\left(y\right)+\int_{b}^{\infty}0dF\left(y\right)=\left(b-a\right)F\left(a\right)+b\left(F\left(b\right)-F\left(a\right)\right)-\int_{a}^{b}ydF\left(y\right)=$$$$bF\left(b\right)-aF\left(a\right)-\int_{a}^{b}ydF\left(y\right)$$

You can apply this on $\Phi(x)$ (and will end up with the final answer of Ionza).